# Zooming further in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a wmts server where the highest zoom level seem to be 9.
This is because if I add in attribute maxZoom something higher than 9, then no tails are fetched and I see 404 in console.

So I found out that the files on the server are from level 0 to level 9.

Now, I want to zoom further in the tiles.
I saw for example this question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687120/leaflet-zoom-in-further-and-stretch-tiles
```

So adding:

```
maxNativeZoom: 10
```

should make the trick, right?

However, if I double click or click on the zoom in (which is disabled, as by default the zoom is already at 9) nothing happens I cannot see the tiles zoomed in.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the information provided, you should set `maxNativeZoom` to `9`, *not* to `10`.

Comment: Setting it at 9, then I get a NAN. The function L.LatLng is called and for some reason the lat and long are passed as NaN.

Comment: Oh sorry, the NaN doesn't depend of maxNativeZoom. Even without it, I still got that error message.

Comment: We'd need to see some code running (jsfiddle, codepen, jsbin or similar) to know what's going on.