# Leaflet.js (or other solution) zoom to magnified pixels without blur

Tags: leaflet, zooming, interpolation, pixel, raster

I've been using Leaflet to display raster images lately.

What I would like to do for a particular project is be able to zoom in to an image so the pixels become magnified on the screen in a sharply delineated way, such as you would get when zooming in to an image in Photoshop or the like. I would also like to retain, at some zoom level before maximum, a 1:1 correspondence between image pixel and screen pixel.

I tried going beyond maxNativeZoom as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687120/leaflet-zoom-in-further-and-stretch-tiles) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277770/why-empty-tiles-when-zoomed-too-much-in-leaflet-js), which works but the interpolation results in pixel blurring.

I thought of an alternative which is to make the source image much larger using 'nearest neighbour' interpolation to expand each pixel into a larger square: when zoomed to maxNativeZoom the squares then look like sharply magnified pixels even though they aren't.

Problems with this are:

- image size and tile count get out of hand quickly (original image is 4096 x 4096)
- you never get the 'pop' of a 1:1 correspondence between image pixel and screen pixel

I have thought about using two tile sets: the first from the original image up to it's maxNativeZoom, and then the larger 'nearest neighbour' interpolated image past that, following something like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152186/leaflet-can-i-use-a-different-background-tile-provider-depending-on-zoom-level?rq=1).

But, this is more complex, doesn't avoid the problem of large tile count, and just seems inelegant.

So:

- Can Leaflet do  what I need it to and if so how?
- If not can you point me in the right direction to something that can (for example, it would be interesting to know how [this](https://www.csfieldguide.org.nz/en/interactives/pixel-viewer/) is achieved)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to leverage the [`image-rendering` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering). This can hint the browser to use nearest-neighbour interpolation on `<img>` elements, such as Leaflet map tiles.

e.g.:

```
img.leaflet-tile {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

See a [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/yuEy28vXpiB3LpSc). Beware of [incomplete browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: crisp-edges rather than pixelated seems to have slightly better browser support and is doing just what I want, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A more complicated approach (but one that works across more browsers) is to leverage [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/WebGL); in particular [Leaflet.TileLayer.GL](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL).

This involves some [internal changes to Leaflet.TileLayer.GL to support a per-tile uniform](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL/-/commit/67be298680d0451d33359990a54f195eecef3474#856c3cea7a3d9ede72080956e814db0776551166_329_334), most critically setting the uniform value to the tile coordinate in each tile render...

```js
gl.uniform3f(this._uTileCoordsPosition, coords.x, coords.y, coords.z);
```

...having a `L.TileLayer` that "displays" a non-overzoomed tile for overzoomed tile coordinates (instead of just skipping the non-existent tiles)...

```js
var hackishTilelayer = new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    maxNonPixelatedZoom: 3
});

hackishTilelayer.getTileUrl = function(coords) {
    if (coords.z > this.options.maxNonPixelatedZoom) {
        return this.getTileUrl({
            x: Math.floor(coords.x / 2),
            y: Math.floor(coords.y / 2),
            z: coords.z - 1
        });
    }

    // Skip L.TileLayer.prototype.getTileUrl.call(this, coords), instead
    // apply the URL template directly to avoid maxNativeZoom shenanigans
    var data = {
        r: L.Browser.retina ? '@2x' : '',
        s: this._getSubdomain(coords),
        x: coords.x,
        y: coords.y,
        z: coords.z // *not* this._getZoomForUrl() !
    };
    var url = L.Util.template(this._url, L.Util.extend(data, this.options));
    return url;
}
```

... plus a fragment shader that rounds down texel coordinates prior to texel fetches (plus a tile-coordinate-modulo-dependant offset), to actually perform the nearest-neighbour oversampling...

```js
var fragmentShader = `
highp float factor = max(1., pow(2., uTileCoords.z - uPixelatedZoomLevel));
vec2 subtileOffset = mod(uTileCoords.xy, factor);

void main(void) {
    vec2 texelCoord = floor(vTextureCoords.st * uTileSize / factor ) / uTileSize;

    texelCoord.xy += subtileOffset / factor;

    vec4 texelColour = texture2D(uTexture0, texelCoord);

    // This would output the image colours "as is"
    gl_FragColor = texelColour;
}
`;
```

...all tied together in an instance of `L.TileLayer.GL` (which syncs some numbers for the uniforms around):

```js
var pixelated = L.tileLayer.gl({
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
    tileLayers: [hackishTilelayer],
    uniforms: {
        // The shader will need the zoom level as a uniform...
        uPixelatedZoomLevel: hackishTilelayer.options.maxNonPixelatedZoom,
        // ...as well as the tile size in pixels.
        uTileSize: [hackishTilelayer.getTileSize().x, hackishTilelayer.getTileSize().y]
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

You can see everything working together [in this demo](https://ivansanchez.gitlab.io/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL/demo/demo-pixelated.html).

Comment: I would like to try this but not sure how to apply it to a local tiled image. Have tried replacing the open street map pngs in hackishTileLayer, and a few other things, but no luck so far.